# Hiding php echo output with json and ajax request

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm having the problem running php script right when the page loads, and the output is then displayed on the page, which I dont actually want to display. I tried to hide echo with.

```
<div style='display:none>
```

but, still doesn't work. I have an idea that "Ajax and JSON Encode function()" will help me to solve this issue of 'making ajax request to same page'. But, I real don't know how to create an array to encode html and php variable that are responsible for the results. Help please.

Here's my ajax function to show the output.

```
 function mass() 
 {
     $.ajax({
         url: "page.php",
         cache: false,
         success: function(html){
             $("#container").html(html);
         }
     });
 }
```

Here's my php script that hold the output of the page

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (isset($_REQUEST['AnswerId'])){
    $AnswerId = $_REQUEST['AnswerId'];
}
else {
    $AnswerId = 0;
}               

$i=0;
while ($mytablerow = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $mytable[$i] = $mytablerow;
    $i++;
}

function tree($treeArray, $level, $pid = 0) {
    global $AnswerId;
    if (! $treeArray) {
        return;
    }   
    foreach($treeArray as $item) {
        if ($item[1] == $pid) {
        ?>
        <div class="Div" style="margin-left:<?php echo($level*60);?>px">    
        <div class="CotDiv">
        <div class="ser"><?php echo($item[2]) ; ?></div>
        <div class="Mse"><?php echo($item[3]) ; ?></div>
        <div class="ito"><?php echo($item[4]) ; ?></div>
        <?php               
        if ($level<=40) { 
            echo '<a href="" class="ReplyLink"  onclick="AnswerComment('.$item[0].');return false;">Reply</a>'; }
            echo '<a href="" class="DeleteLink" onclick="DeleteComment('.$item[0].');return false;">Delete</a>';
            ?> </div> <?php

            if ($AnswerId == $item[0]){?> 
                <div id="InnerDiv"><?php ShowForm($AnswerId);?</div><?php ?> </div><?php 
                echo ('<br/>');
                tree($treeArray, $level+1, $item[0]);
            }       
        }
    }
    tree($mytable, 0);
?>
```

Comment: How much of the content do you want to display in the Ajax response? If no content is desired, don't call the Ajax request.

Comment: The data tha i want to display in the ajax response are those on the divs tags <div></div> and <a></a>. How can I display them

Comment: Try `ob_*` set of functions  output buffering sounds like what you want http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Thank for your advice, i'm going to try that too. But, how can I do that in JSON encode function and Ajax to display data and avoid the duplicate output in the page when page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@enance this isn't the exact same code, but the idea is the same. This probably doesn't output correctly because I don't have an example array of the mysql output to test.

Just a few notes, try not to use globals and just pass the variable into the function. For the sake of time, I kept the output of html within this function, but ideally you'll like to output html through another function.

```
<?php
// example array
$mytable = [
 [1,0,3,4,5,6],
 [0,2,3,4,5,6]
];

$answer_id = 1;

function tree($answer_id, $items, $level, $pid = 0) {
  if (empty($array))
    return;

  foreach ($items as $item) {

    if ($item[1] == $pid) {
      echo sprintf('<div class="Div" style="margin-left:%spx">',$level * 60);
      echo '<div class="CotDiv">';
      echo sprintf('<div class="ser">%s</div>', $item[2]);
    } 

    if ($level <= 40) {
      echo sprintf('<a href="" class="ReplyLink" onclick="AnswerComment(%s);return false;">Reply</a>', $item[0]);
      echo sprintf('<a href="" class="DeleteLink" onclick="DeleteComment(%2);return false;">Delete</a>', $item[0]);
    }

    echo '</div>';

    if ($answer_id == $item[0]) {
      echo sprintf('<div id="InnerDiv">%s</div>', 'FORM OUTPUT HERE');
      tree($answer_id, $items, $level++, $item[0]);
    }

    echo '</div>';
  }

}

tree($answer_id, $mytable, 0);
exit;
```

I really hope this helps to get you on the right track.